# Get the forecasted values when using forecast() in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I did a forecast() in R, and I only want the forecasted values.  How can I do this? If I use `forecast$means` I get extra information instead of a usable data object like a vector.

```
suppressMessages(require('forecast'))
suppressMessages(require('rjson'))

# Load data. Let user choose what file they want to input.
my_json = "[1,2,3,4,5]"

my_data = fromJSON(my_json)

my_df = data.frame(my_data)

# Plot the decomposed time series. Let user choose their season length.
forecasted_data = forecast(ts(my_df[,1]), h=5)

print(forecasted_data$mean)
```

Current Output:

```
Time Series:
Start = 6 
End = 10 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 4.9999 4.9999 4.9999 4.9999 4.9999
```

Desired Output:

```
[1] 4.9999 4.9999 4.9999 4.9999 4.9999
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try stripping the `ts` attributes by coercing it into a simple `numeric` vector:

```
as.numeric(forecasted_data$mean)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Forecasted_data‹-data.frame(forecasted_data)
View(forecasted_data)
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?